# How to write an async for?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some code and I realized that I have an array with 100000+ positions and I have to go through all the positions of the array. However, I also realized that I can "parallelize the for". Now the question, is there a way that I can parallelize the default for.

`for(let i=0 ; i<limit ; i++)`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. Javascript is single threaded, so asking to parallelize something isn't generally possible (or at least isn't trivial). In node you can spawn child processes, is that what you have in mind?

Comment: you'd use `await` inside an `async function`

Comment: Mark Meyer, yes, that is what I have in mind. As example I want to call n positions in array to run in parallel, and 'releasing' the main thread. Do you know a library to make this viable?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, instead of making the looping parallel, make the execution of code in each loop parallel. Here is an async loop function which executes the callback function in parallel.

```
/**
 * @param {Array}  arr: Array of items to loop over
 * @param {Function} cb: Callback function which needs to be executed per item
 * @returns Promise object which will be resolved once all the items have been executed
 */
function asyncFor(arr, cb) {
  const asyncCB = (item) => new Promise(resolve => resolve(cb(item)));
  return Promise.all(arr.map(item => asyncCB(item)));
}
```

Comment: Wrapping things in promises doesn't make them run in parallel. Your callbacks are still going to run one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like stream parallel in java8+? 
Create  workers pool, route the calls to different worker, collect results, and continue..